# Grails setup problems

Tags: grails, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

So i have tried to find this answer but everything seems different from the problem that I am having. I am trying to set grails up so that I can alter an existing program. The problem is that I keep getting errors when ever I try and run the program, I would get NoClassDefFoundErrors and ClassNotFoundException. So I figured that there was a problem with the program and that maybe something got messed up in the file paths when I imported it. Then I tested my grails by trying to create an app and I got the same errors.

I am using grails 2.2 the original version it was written in.

This is the output after I run any operation with grails

```
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
| Error     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
| Error     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
| Error     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1.run(CachedClass.java:84)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:81)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:79)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:250)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.populateMethods(MetaClassImpl.java:340)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.fillMethodIndex(MetaClassImpl.java:290)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2924)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:483)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:176)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:192)
| Error     at groovy.util.ConfigObject.$getStaticMetaClass(ConfigObject.groovy)
| Error     at groovy.util.ConfigObject.<init>(ConfigObject.groovy)
| Error     at grails.util.AbstractBuildSettings.<init>(AbstractBuildSettings.java:33)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.<init>(BuildSettings.groovy)
| Error     at grails.util.BuildSettings.<init>(BuildSettings.groovy:789)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:164)
| Error     ... 6 more
| Error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:48)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
| Error     ... 28 more
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

That's because the version of Groovy used in older versions of Grails doesn't work with Java 8. Either use Java 7, or update to 2.5+ which has a new enough version of Groovy.